# FFmpeg: Unrecognized option preset

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg` to convert yuv to mp4 losslesly in ubuntu 14.04.

My code is (without line splitting):

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 560x448 -r 40 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i 
C_L_560x448_40_realtime_maxSSIM.yuv -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 
realtimeC_L_560x448_40_realtime_maxSSIM.mp4
```

I get

```
Unrecognized option 'preset'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

This is the full console output:

```
ffmpeg version N-80953-gd4c8e93 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration:
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 50.100 / 57. 50.100
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
Unrecognized option 'preset'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of ffmpeg do you have? Show the console output.

Comment: @Mulvya I added it right now.

Comment: You don't have libx265 (or any 3rd party encoders) linked. Get a binary from http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: I just want to add, using ```-qp 0``` isn't the way to do lossless encoding with libx265 (unlike libx264). Instead you need to add in ```-x265-params lossless=1```

Answer (score 1):

For me this meant I had run configure with `--disable-everything` and enabled libx264, but not enabled its "encoder" so this fixed it up: `--enable-libx264 --enable-encoder=libx264`

Something like this:

`ffmpeg $ ./configure --disable-everything --enable-libx264 --enable-encoder=libx264`

You might be able to get away with just `--enable-libx264`

Comment: could you ass the complete cmd? As the answer of the question

Comment: Made an attempt